# Objective-C Modal View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to present a modal view from a UIView or a UIWindow in the same .xib?

here is my code:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {
IBOutlet UIVIew *myView
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *myView;

- (void)somefunction;
```

And my function:

```
- (void)somefunction {
     //here i need to make my view1 gets presented by a modal view style.
}
```

Comment: Why don't you move the view to its own NIB file? It'll decrease the memory footprint of your app and will let the `UIViewController` work the way they are designed to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add IBOutlets for your views. In your MyViewController.h file:

```
...
IBOutlet UIView *firstView;
IBOutlet UIView *secondView;
...
```

Then you connect the outlets using Interface Builder (or Xcode 4). After that, in your implementation file you manually hide or show the view that you want.

**PresenterViewController.m:**

```
- (void)ShowSecondView{

   //Initialize the view controller
   MyViewController *modalView = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];

  //Hide or show whatever view(s) you want
  [modalView.firstView setHidden:YES];
  [modalView.secondView setHidden:NO];  

  //Present the view controller modally
  [self presentModalViewController:modalView animated:YES];

  //Don't forget memory management!
  [modalView release];
}
```

You may need to tweak this code a little bit, but this is the general idea.

Comment: Ok. You didnt understang my question. I have 2 views, the main view loaded and another view, what we'll call "View2". Both are inside of the MainViewController.xib. I want find out how to present the View2 like Modal.

Comment: Ah, ok. You need to define IBOutlets and use those to hide/show the views. For example: `IBOutlet UIView *view1;` etc... Please edit the question, so that I can edit my answer to match.

Comment: MyViewController comes with the default "view" setted. Can i declare it "IBOutlet UIView *view;"?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're asking then. I'm sorry!